# Force a specific program to open while opening a given program

Tags: windows-7, regedit

How to force vlc.exe to open wmplayer.exe using regedit? 
i.e.
whenever and from wherever i try to open windows media player, it should open vlc instead

Comment: Please clarify what you intend to ask. If its that you need to open all your media files in VLC player, then you can set VLC as default program via file association in control panel.

Comment: not that. I want vlc to open when i try to open windows media player. This process is not associated with ant file associations or extensions

Comment: What I get from your post is that you want to intentionally click on WMP and somehow expect another app (VLC) to open. I don't get it. Is there something you forgot to mention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can in theory do this using the registry key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options
```

If you create a key "wmplayer.exe" as a subkey there you can then create a REG_SZ named "debugger" and specify any program to be launched whenever wmplayer is called (Details [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2004/04/28/121871.aspx))

If you use the path to vlc palyer as debugger it will always be started instead of wmplayer.exe. Because it is no debugger wmplayer.exe will not be started but passed to vlc.exe which will not understand it and give an error. To prevent this you could instead use a simple script

```
Set wso = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wso.Run """C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe""", , False ' use your own path to the vlc executable
```

And as debugger specify `"wscript.exe <path to the script>"`

Some things to consider: this will only work correctly with a direct call to wmplayer.exe. All arugments are deleted by the script. This includes media files passed to wmplayer. You can in the script of course also handle arguments and pass them on to vlc. The main problem with this is that wmplayer itself can have several command lines besides a media file so you would have to exclude all that are specific to wmplayer and include all the make sense for vlc which is beyond the scope of your question.

Also note that this is a very hackish approach that I would never use if there is any other way to solve your problem. In fact I would even rather replace the executable with my own vlc portable exe or something but imo the question is answerable, so it should be answered.

Comment: Clever. Very clever.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear to me what you want to do, but would

1. Rename `wmplayer.exe` to  `wmplayer_bak.exe`, and
2. copy `vlc.exe` to  `wmplayer.exe`

do what you want?